# Stack overflow links not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow

Most of the links on stackoverflow are not working. I suspect it is due to a js that is not being loaded.

I am getting following error in console. Can anyone please suggest on how to get rid of this error?

[image]

The problem occurs only for stackoverflow dropdowns/links. No issues in other communities.

The problem occurs in chrome and FF. Please note, I logged into stackoverflow using FF for first time.

Comment: What is your exact url you are using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: Just as a side note: the page work here. Are you blocking some javascript? Ads maybe?

Comment: I have checked the settings and I confirm that I am not blocking javascript.

Comment: e.g. - **Achievements drop down is not opening** only in stackoverflow. In other communities it is working. Similar issue with other drop downs as well.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Are you able to click on the Achievements dropdown. Does it work on the page I mentioned?

Comment: Yes. It all works normally.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Great. Any suggestions for me as how can I resolve this issue? The problem is all browsers on my machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, that javascript loading isn't from StackExchange. Something is in the middle fiddling with your request.

The IP address mentioned belongs to an Indian telephone company, and the host name can't be resolved at the time. If you know the company hosting **mtnl.net.in** you might have a clue what the source of the problem is ([some networking information](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=203.94.243.63)). Is it your ISP? Have you got an not very up to date router which was compromised? Maybe your work that tries to fiddle with your Internet requests?

Second, *maybe* the missing javascript isn't the actual issue with your not-working StackOverflow. Can you check the errors in the console tab? Can you try to browse StackOverflow over HTTPS?

Comment: https works like charm. Additionally yes, mtnl is my ISP. What should I do to fix the problem due to this?

Comment: There is a problem - Whenever, I navigated the protocol changes back to http and then again some problems. I need to fix it badly.

Comment: Contact your ISP. Or change it immediately. This sounds suspicious...

Comment: Well ISP tracking and messing with traffic is not surprising, but I would expect it more in places like China or Iran...

Comment: MTNL is a [known code-injector](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/issues/5999).

Answer (score 7):

Based on your screenshot, most likely you got some malware on your machine that try to load a resource called "getjs", which is **not part of Stack Exchange**.

Run full virus scan, malware detection program, etc, and it would hopefully be resolved.

Comment: I have tried doing that. But no success. There is an issue only with stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Still, something on your end. Might even be on your ISP side. Try different computer, different connection, and see.

Comment: I tried checking on different computer and the same problem again. Let me check all possible options suggested and will revert back.

Comment: Well things worked fine with my friend who is using other ISP. And as suggested by Patrick, things worked fine over https.

Comment: @nikhil so it is most likely your ISP, cheers for finding a workaround! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help :)