# Stack Overflow Up, Down Vote and Favorite (star) buttons are not working

Tags: support

I'm trying to vote up a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). But button does not working, then i open other some question for checking but these (Up Vote, Down Vote, Favorite star) are not working. Also this error is showing.

[image]

Comment: @DeerHunter Yes this Locked post but I also checked some others, same  issue on all.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when connecting over HTTPS?

Comment: @DeerHunter Ohh i check with `HTTPS` now its working. Thank You

Comment: It might be that your ISP injects javascript (for advertisements) in http/html content. There are similar reports

Comment: Are you from India? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318384/stackoverflow-js-is-down/318395#318395

Comment: No, from UAE dubai

Comment: Oh, there is an upvote button? Forgot about that feature entirely....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should switch to HTTPS since your ISP is evidently [MITMing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) your connection to inject advertisements (and does so by ruining valid JavaScript).

You should really consider switching to another ISP, because an ISP that introduces a Man-In-The-Middle attack is in fact hacking your connection and you shouldn't assume it's [benign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_(computer_security))  (original advice [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318395)).

Please note that there is an long standing and on-going effort to fully support secure connections over HTTPS/TLS across the Stack Exchange network that is riddled by both technical challenges and costs. See [Accessing per-site metas gives 403 forbidden from cloudflare-nginx](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx) among other posts on the subject. Among the meta sites only MSE, MSO, MSU, MSF, and Meta Ask Ubuntu support TLS, yet all main sites are accessible through a secure connection.

Other things to consider:

- Make your browser disallow mixed content (with, e.g. NoScript and HTTPS Everywhere browser extensions).
- Force the browser to use TLS for **all** Stack Exchange and related sites (through NoScript settings, for instance), including sstatic.net, imgur.com, stackauth.com, gravatar.com etc.
- Fiddle with parameters until you see no mixed/dubious content is being loaded.
- Thoroughly check what Certificate Authorities your browser trusts.
- To securely access site metas other than those listed above, use either mobile apps, or Emacs with the SX extension.

<sub>This post is intentionally made community wiki since I have already posted practically the same answer over at M.SO.</sub>

---

Related questions:

- [Stack overflow links not working](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266211/stack-overflow-links-not-working)
- [Roadmap for HTTPS/SSL support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226030/roadmap-for-https-ssl-support)

Comment: You sure there is a "on-going" effort?

Comment: @Zizouz212 - please feel free to edit that in. That's a community wiki, after all.

Comment: @Zizouz212 - I'm not sure if anything can be done at this point. SE users are being hacked, and that was predicted many times.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226030/roadmap-for-https-ssl-support

Comment: @Zizouz212 - it is certainly ongoing, however slowly (there are a lot of considerations for us to complete the work and a bunch of complications).